# Flutter json_serializable different reference key name switch request

Tags: flutter, json-serializable

I'm asking a question and not found an similar post for this.

I explain, I use json_serializable, but webservice provide some information of the same type of object by with different name keys, exemple :

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Group {
  Group(
      this.id,
      this.name,
      this.owner,
      this.description);

  int id;
  String name;
  User owner; //Here owner are only "id" and "name"
  String? description;

...
}

@JsonSerializable()
class User {
  User(this.uid, this.nom, this.mail, this.prenom);

  String? uid;
  late String mail;
  String nom;
  String? prenom;

...
```

So "id" and "uid" are different key but for same value, and same things for "name" and "nom".

There is any way for indicate to generator this can be different name of key for same value ..?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to set two different variable witch one will can be NULL